# Setting WinSCP with explicit TLS encryption

Tags: ftp, winscp, ftps

I am trying to connect to a FTP server with following setting

[image: winscp UI setting]

This setting works well and I can connect to FTP server via GUI (version 5.7.5)

However, when I try to convert these settings to script

```
winscp.com /command "option batch abort" "option confirm off" "open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com:21 -   
explicittls /" "put -filemask=>1D  D:\Backups\*.bak /" "exit"
```

and run it from `cmd`, there is an error message indicated that there is

> Too many parameters for command 'open'."

What did I do wrong here and how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's

```
winscp.com /command "open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/ -explicit" ...
```

or simply

```
winscp.com /command "open ftpes://username:password@ftp.example.com/"
```

See:

- https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open
- https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url

You get the *"Too many parameters for command 'open'"* because of the `/` after the `explicittls`. Or because of the `explicittls` itself, if you really have the spaces there in-between the `-` and the `explicittls`.

---

You can use [Generate Transfer Code Dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script) to have WinSCP generate the script or batch file for you.

[image: Generate transfer code]

---

Side notes:

- `option batch abort` and `option confirm off` are [not necessary since 5.7 anymore](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#using_scripting) (they are implicit with `/command`);
- you do not need to specify port `21`, it's the default port for FTP;

Answer (score 0):

Try the following line:

```
winscp.com /command "option batch abort" "option confirm off" "open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com:21 -   
explicittls" "put -filemask=>1D  D:\Backups\*.bak /" "exit"
```